# After Yosemite, Genymotion and Android Studio failed to work together

Tags: android, mobile, osx-yosemite, genymotion

Error: adb server is out of date.  killing...
cannot bind 'tcp:5037'
ADB server didn't ACK
Android Studion 0.8.9 (beta) was working fine with Maverick using Genymotion for emulator. Don't quote me on this but the problem started a few days after i upgraded to Yosemite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For various compatibility reasons to maintain a delicate balance with gradle and the latest google libraries, I have updated my `Android Studio to version 0.9.2`, as of writing, this is in the Canary branch.

Gradle is 0.14.+

Gradle Wrapper also must be the latest version if you use Gradle 0.14.+

OSX is Yosemite 10.10

My Android Build tools are up to 21.1.1

I have Android 5.0 API level 21 installed

ADB version is 1.0.32

**and Genymotion is updated 2.3.1**

**Genymotion is set to use my custom android sdk tools instead of it's own built in ones, Settings > ADB > Use custom Android SDK tools**

let me know if you still have issues, everything was broken for me for a little while too. Make sure ADB is still on your path and that it is the correct version ("adb version" on the command line, without quotes), in some cases newer versions of Android Studio make you move the android sdk folder location.

Answer (score 0):

Try killing your adb service (it's probably still running).  Then restart Android Studio.

Comment: The same error comes up if I kill it manually and start the studio. Partially your suggestion is helpful. I had to kill genymotion, the studio and manually kill adb. Then start studio followed by genymotion.  (I wonder why my question was down voted ?)